# TensorBoard graph is ugly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I hope someone had the same problem. My TensorBoard graph looks very cluttered, and I'm having trouble understanding it. I'm trying to implement a neural network for denoising, but I'm wondering if anyone knows why there are many "sub_1," "sub_2," etc. names and how I can make it more organized.

Here you can see the TensorBoard graph and also how far it extends in length.
[TensorBoard graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGdvh.png)

If I add these lines of code to my code, at the beginning:

```
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)
```

And at the end:

```
with tf.summary.create_file_writer(name_logs_directory).as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(
        name="my_graph",
        step=0,
        profiler_outdir=name_logs_directory
    )
```

And I insert some "`with tf.name_scope("")` to divide the various actions into macro-actions, at the end of the training I get a sequence of graphs as shown in the figure.
[Tensorboard graph custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRS1g.png)